# Environment Variable - Startup Folder

Tags: assembly, environment-variables, startup, fasm, startup-folder

Is there an Environment Variable for the startup folder.

On XP it is located under C:\Documents and Settings(user)\Start Menu\Programs\Startup and on vista 7 it is under Appdata\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\

So I was wondering if there was an EnVar for this folder?

Comment: Why are you tagging this with `assembly` and an assembler?

Comment: Well im coding in FASM right now, that is why I need this answer, for an asm project. I just failed to mention that in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you create binaries, why don't you use  CSIDL_STARTMENU  with SHGetFolderPathA?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Note that on Vista and above SHGetFolderPath is deprecated and replaced by SHGetKnownFolderPath.